# Read lines from a file in chunks

Tags: file, iterator, perl, generator

I created a function to read lines from an file into chunks. 
My hidden agenda in creation this script was in python the **yield** function in interaction with **chunks**.
The script works fine, but now i want to know if anyone has improvements?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;


sub read_in_chunks {
    my $args = shift;
    my $self = {
        fd => $args->{fd} || undef,
        chunk_size => $args->{chunk_size} || 10,
        chunks => [],
    };
    my $fh = $self->{fd};
    return unless defined(my $line=<$fh>);
    while(<$fh>){
        chomp($_);
        # maybe the following line could be written nicer :)
        ($self->{chunk_size} == 0) ? return $self->{chunks} : (push @{$self->{chunks}}, $_);
        $self->{chunk_size}--;
    }
    return $self->{chunks};
}

open my $fh, 'dump.txt' or die $!;

my $opts = {
    fd => $fh,
    chunk_size => 4
};

while(my $chunk = read_in_chunks($opts)) {
    print Dumper($chunk);
    # process data
}

close $fh;
```

Comment: What happens to the line read by `$line=<$fh>`?

Comment: it returns if $line=<$fh> is not defined

Comment: Yes, but if it's defined, it gets lost.

Comment: @choroba: maybe you have an Idea how i can improve my code snippet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my take. I removed the $self structure, as it gives you no advantage, and fixed the problem with missing lines.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use Data::Dumper;

sub read_in_chunks {
    my %args = @_;
    my $fh = $args{fh} or die "No filehandle given.\n";
    my $size = $args{chunk_size} || 10;
    my @chunk;
    while (@chunk < $size && defined(my $line = <$fh>)) {
        chomp $line;
        push @chunk, $line;
    }
    return @chunk
}

open my $fh, shift or die $!;

my %opts = (
    fh         => $fh,
    chunk_size => 4
);

while (my @chunk = read_in_chunks(%opts)) {
    print Dumper(\@chunk);
    # ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks to You @choroba . Do. You think Reading big Files is better and faster when Reading in Chucky? I Know this answer can only be answered if you make an Time measure.

Comment: @Patrick85: Definitely not this way. You can try [read](http://p3rl.org/read) or [sysread](http://p3rl.org/sysread) or reading with `$/` set to a reference to a number.

Answer (score 0):

Untested,

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

sub read_in_chunks {
    my ($args) = @_;

    my $chunk_size = $args->{chunk_size};
    my $fh = $args->{fd} or die "no filehandle";

    return sub {
        $chunk_size ||= 10;
        my $chunks = [];
        # my $line = <$fh> // return;
        while (my $line = <$fh>) {
            chomp($line);

            last if !$chunk_size;
            push @$chunks, $line;
            $chunk_size--;
        }
        return @$chunks ? $chunks : undef;
    };
}

open my $fh, '<', 'dump.txt' or die $!;

my $opts = {
    fd => $fh,
    chunk_size => 4,
};
my $iter = read_in_chunks($opts);

while (my $chunk = $iter->()) {
    print Dumper($chunk);
    # process data
}
```